# get text within bracket if matches keyword

Tags: php, regex

So I want to get the text within the square brackets(without brackets) if a keyword is matched within the brackets.

so the keyword works but for example "test [work all day] test" it returns everything in the brackets and outside as well .

so far i have the below, but I only want it to return everything within the brackets(without bracekts) if the keyword "work" is matched within the brackets.

```
preg_match('/.*(\[work.*?\]).*/', $res, $match)
```

Comment: `preg_match('/\[(?=.*?\bwork\b)(.*?)\]/', $res, $match)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `php`, but I can provide an answer for the regex pattern.

Use this:

```
(?<=\[)work[^\]]*
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=\[)`: lookbehind to verify that the string begins with an open bracket
- `work`: literal match
- `[^\]]*`: negated character class with `*` quantifier which matches every other character except a closed bracket (the first closed bracket is escaped)

Now, you get a string which is preceded with an open bracket, and is matched up to the point before the closing bracket.

[Verify here](https://regex101.com/r/YkT9MZ/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain of the specifics for using this in PHP, but it works in JavaScript this way.

```
let src = "test [work all day] test"
console.log(src.replace( /.*\[(work.*?)\].*/g, "$1"));
```

Please put the part you want to extract in parentheses and replace the entire string with $1.

$1 refers to the contents of the first parenthesis.
It will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could match `work` between the square brackets, assuming there are no occurrences of other square brackets in between.

```
\[\K[^][]*\bwork\b[^][]*(?=])
```

**Explanation**

- `\[` Match `[`
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `[^][]*` Match optional chars other than `[` or `]`
- `\bwork\b` Match the word `work`
- `[^][]*` Match optional chars other than `[` or `]`
- `(?=])` Positive lookahead, assert `]` to the right

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/hM7u2d/1).

```
$res = "test [work all day] test";
$pattern = '/\[\K[^][]*\bwork\b[^][]*(?=])/';

if (preg_match($pattern, $res, $match)) {
    echo $match[0];
}
```

Output

```
work all day
```

Comment: This is most suitable answer.